# Using a pixel fire, is it possible to get the "image" headers to report back and allow the client browser to run load html, via that image?

Tags: javascript, html, .htaccess

Is it possible to use a pixel to load html into the client browser, and have that browser load the html?

I'm thinking it might be possible with .htaccess header modifications, but I need the individual viewing the pixel fire to load the html, and have their browser read it.

Answer (score 0):

No, a browser will expect an image, if a HTML document is returned (this is common for 404s, or firewalls that block access to certain websites) then the browser processes it as a broken image, it does not process the HTML.